# How to check if a file exists in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to determine if a file exists in C++ 11

I have the following codes:

```
ifstream inputFile(c);

if (!inputFile.good()) {
        std::cout << "No file found" << '\n';           
}
```

And

```
if (inputFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()){
           ....
}
```

Which one is correct and idiomatic?

Comment: What version (`c++11`, `c++14`, ...) of C++ are you using? The suggested / "most idiomatic" solutions may differ based on that.

Comment: @druckernamly edited, c++ 11

Comment: Just mentioning: if you have access to C++17, then `std::filesystem::exists` is there.

Comment: I guess your intent is to check whether the file is readable or not by your process. It is a bit different from just testing if this file exists; it could exist but your process may not be able to read its content (permissions...).

Comment: The first one looks better to me. Why check if an arbitrary file-related function returns an error, if you can directly check if the file was opened correctly.

Comment: You almost never want to check if a file exists. If you need to open a file, go ahead and try opening it, and deal with possible errors. You need to deal with errors anyway.

Answer (score 12):

In C++17 you have `<filesystem>` with which you can do:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::path f{ "file.txt" };
if (fs::exists(f)) std::cout << "yes";
else               std::cout << "nope";
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that even if the file exists, then it may not be possible to open it or read or write it. It may also be deleted by some other process an instant after the check returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to determine if a file exist using C++11 you may want to try this idea

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::ifstream file("myfile.txt");
    if(!file.is_open()){
        std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this with `"/etc/shadow"` or `"/etc/sudoers"` ;^)

Comment: Although this is just a common solution, if you're not specific in your solution

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: the std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::good returns true when the IO operation was done most recently, and may not be the right or proper solution. Except you have something in mind to achieve and maybe the question wasn't properly asked.

Comment: It's not really important, just a matter of vocabulary. I think that the fact that a file exists or not is different from the fact that this file is readable or not. Your example tests if the file is readable and if it fails it concludes that this file is not found. It may be actually found but not readable (due to permissions)  by your process. So I would say that this file is not "readable". (no big deal...)

Comment: I guess so, i stand corrected.